# AngularJS moving dynamic data to controller

Tags: php, angularjs

**Hello.**

- How can one pass dynamic data to controller -> view?

Background :

Im making a forum, making it with PHP & AngularJS.

```
 <td><a ng-click="setRoute('forum')" href="#/forums?id=<?php echo $f_id;?>"><?php echo $f_name;?></a></td>
```

That is my link, those variables has been set earlier (not relevant).

```
.when('/forums?:id', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/forums/forums.php',
})
```

That is my Routeprovider.

**So how can I store that :id/?id= to a controller?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start using [RouteParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams). Here is a good explanation: https://thinkster.io/egghead/routeparams-api